# MCMC Metropolis Hastings

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

Does anyone know a webpage or a document where I can find a practical example of implementation of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, with some thoughts about burn-in time and how to construct the transition matrix?

Comment: I think it'd be useful to give some more details and background on what you're looking for, since the subject is huge. What is your background/experience, what are you hoping to do, and have you already read some literature on the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implemented in Matlab](http://www.quantiphile.com/2010/11/01/metropolis-hastings/). Only really covers the implementation. Do note Gerben's comment below: The burn-in time purported to be a "rule of thumb" by the author is by no means so.

[In Python](http://code.google.com/p/pymc/).

Comment: I'm not sure if you're the author of said webpage, but there are some things that I don't really agree with. As for the 'burn-in time': I'm currently working on a very canonical model which, however, has a burn-in time of ~ 8 billion iterations - just to state that no real rule of thumb exists for things like burn-in time in Monte Carlo.

Comment: @Gerben Oh, no, not the author by a long shot. Just something I found while reading about it. I certainly don't condone the use of any rules of thumb, in Monte Carlo or otherwise. Edited to reflect your comment.